# Get substring from string in javascript with a pattern

Tags: javascript

How can I get substring from string in javascript that match a pattern?
I have this string,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#efefef"
          style="background: #efefef; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
               style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0 12px 0;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%">Webmail App
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="50%">
                                            <div style="color: #5d5d5d; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 1px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align: right;">
                                                {{current_date}}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                <div style="background-color: #0065b2; color: #fbfbfb; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; padding: 16px 12px 16px 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                                    Application for {{application_position}}
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color: #4676fd; color: #efefef; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 16px 12px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                                    {{applicant_name}}
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color: #fffff; color: #0E2334; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; padding: 24px 12px 8px 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                                    this is a sample message.
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color: #fffff; color: #0E2334; text-align: left;">
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color: #fffff; color: #0E2334; text-align: left; padding: 24px 12px 8px 12px; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.5px;">
                                    Thanks,<br/>{{staff_name}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 0 20px 0;"><p
                style="color: #666; font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0.5px; font-weight: 500; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                                    Thank you for using Webmail<br/> </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
```

This is a string. I used it in email templates. How can I get all substring that match with,

```
{{something_code}}
```

So the output must be, an array with values of,

```
["current_date","application_position","applicant_name","staff_name"]
```

These values are  dynamic. it depends to the template how many special codes they have.

Also the values must be unique.

I tried filter function but not working. How can I do it? any sample to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string is withing a variable named `html_str`

`var results = html_str.match(/[^{{}}]+(?=\})/g);`

`results` will be an array. So for the html posted by you `results` will be `["current_date","application_position","applicant_name","staff_name"]`

Comment: This is fast. But I found a solution for my problem. instead of getting all special code in the html, i will just replace the substring. so i dont need to get the match values. But thanks to the answer.